# Increase sda1 storage size from sda2 space in Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, mount, ram

I want to increase the storage size of sda1. Below is my pydf command output.

```
megha@megha-medion:~$ pydf 
Filesystem  Size  Used Avail Use%                                                            Mounted on         
/dev/sda3   550G   64G  458G 11.6 [######..................................................] /                  
/dev/sda1  1274G 1080G  194G 84.8 [###############################################.........] /media/megha/Data  
/dev/sdb5  1020M  265M  755M 26.0 [###############.........................................] /media/megha/PRC_RP
```

I have a requirement that /dev/sda3 should have at least 1200GB's of space. Can I somehow extend /dev/sda3 partition space from `/dev/sda1(reducing /dev/sda1 space)`. Now in the output, it shows

```
/dev/sda1  1274G 1080G  194G 84.8 [###############################################.........] /media/megha/Data
```

just because I have moved my contents from /dev/sda3 to /dev/sda1 to check if it works for me. But It does not. So I am moving it back to /dev/sda3.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes its possible. But before you do anything back up your data somewhere. You can create a partition and then create a PV and attach that to a LV and resize it. remember when u create a PV it does format so becarefull if you are not sure what you are doing.If you are not confident enough with terminal use some GUI based Applications like GParted for instance